# show option count in dependent select

Tags: php, ajax

I want to show option count near select box. following code shows the dependent select boxes.
For more clarity I want to show the count as follows.

Province : select a province  (9)
District : select a district  (25)

if a province is selected, then have to show the number of districts comes under the selected province and have to show name of the districts as select options.

Following is the javascript code

```
$('.act').change(function(){
      if($(this).val() != '')
      {
       var action = $(this).attr("id");
       var query = $(this).val();
       var result = '';
       if(action == "province")
       {
        result = 'district';
       }
       else if(action == "district")
       {
        result = 'ds';
       } 
       else if(action == "ds")
       {
        result = 'gn_div';
       }

       else if(action == "gn_div")
       {
        result = 'village';
       }
       $.ajax({
        url:"views/fetch.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{action:action, query:query},
        success:function(data){
         $('#'+result).html(data);
        }
       })
    }
});
```

Following php code is used to fetch required records

```
<?php
//fetch.php

require ('../config/dbconnection.php');

$a=0;

if(isset($_POST["action"]))
{

 $output = '';
 $count = '';
 if($_POST["action"] == "province")
 {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `district` WHERE province_id= '".$_POST["query"]."' AND approved='1'";
 // echo $query;
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
  $output .= '<option value="">Select a District</option>';
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $output .= '<option value="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["district_code"].': '.$row['name_english'].'</option>';
}
 }
 if($_POST["action"] == "district")
 {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `divisional_secretariat` WHERE district_id = '".$_POST["query"]."' AND approved='1'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
  $output .= '<option value="">Select a Divisional Secretariat</option>';
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

   $output .= '<option value="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["divisional_secretariat_code"].': '.$row['name_english'].'</option>';
  }
 }

 if($_POST["action"] == "ds")
 {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `grama_niladhari_division` WHERE divisional_secretariat_id = '".$_POST["query"]."' AND approved='1'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
  $output .= '<option value="">Select a Grama Niladhari Division</option>';
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
   $output .= '<option value="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["grama_niladhari_division_code"].': '.$row['name_english'].'</option>';
  }
 }

  if($_POST["action"] == "gn_div")
 {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `village` WHERE grama_niladhari_division_id = '".$_POST["query"]."' AND approved='1'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
  $output .= '<option value="">Select a Village</option>';
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
   $output .= '<option value="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["village_code"].': '.$row['name_english'].'</option>';
  }
 }
 echo $output;

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the number of rows in result set using [`mysqli_num_rows`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php). And then return both output and count of rows.

```
<?php

require ('../config/dbconnection.php');

$a = 0;

if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $output = '';
    $count = 0;

    if ($_POST['action'] === 'province') {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `district` WHERE province_id = '{$_POST['query']}' AND approved = '1'";

        $output = '<option value="">Select a District</option>';

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $output .= '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['district_code'] . ': ' . $row['name_english'] . '</option>';
        }
    } elseif ($_POST['action'] === 'district') {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `divisional_secretariat` WHERE district_id = '{$_POST['query']}' AND approved='1'";

        $output = '<option value="">Select a Divisional Secretariat</option>';

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $output .= '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['divisional_secretariat_code'] . ': ' . $row['name_english'] . '</option>';
        }
    } elseif ($_POST['action'] === 'ds') {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `grama_niladhari_division` WHERE divisional_secretariat_id = '{$_POST['query']}' AND approved='1'";

        $output = '<option value="">Select a Grama Niladhari Division</option>';

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $output .= '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['grama_niladhari_division_code'] . ': ' . $row['name_english'] . '</option>';
        }
    } elseif ($_POST['action'] === 'gn_div') {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `village` WHERE grama_niladhari_division_id = '{$_POST['query']}' AND approved='1'";

        $output = '<option value="">Select a Village</option>';

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $output .= '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['village_code'] . ': ' . $row['name_english'] . '</option>';
        }
    }

    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    echo json_encode([
        'output' => $output,
        'count' => $count
    ]);
}
```

You should get json response in your Javascript:

```
$('.act').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        var action = $(this).attr('id');
        var query = $(this).val();
        var result = '';

        if (action === 'province') {
            result = 'district';
        } else if (action === 'district') {
            result = 'ds';
        } else if (action === 'ds') {
            result = 'gn_div';
        } else if (action === 'gn_div') {
            result = 'village';
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: 'views/fetch.php',
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            data: {action:action, query:query},
            success: function(data) {
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                $('#' + result).html(data.output);

                /* Use data.count to get number of results returned */
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And do not forget to use **[Prepared Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.html)**.